# vbscript window.onload is not working in IE11

Tags: html, dom, vbscript

In a classic asp page,where hundreds lines of code(asp,Javascript,vbscript and Html) are written.
I am getting an issue, here is my code:

```
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">    
      Sub Window_OnLoad()
        Document.SveForm2.submit()             
      End Sub       
   </script>
    <form name="SveForm2" action="<%=action%>" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="txtUserId" value="<%=UserId%>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="txtAction" value="<%=action%>" />

    </form>
```

this code is working fine in IE8 and IE9 but not working in IE11 . please suggest.

Comment: Are you trying to use VBScript client-side? (Why?) You may need to turn on compatibility mode for this to work on IE11.

Comment: i don't want to change compatibility mode from IE Setting. i just want to do all the things in my code so that end user can easily access webpage without changing any setting.

Comment: This got nothing to do with classic ASP. That code is client side VBScript, and it's not supported anymore in any modern browser. Don't use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use client side VBScript. Period.

That specific code you posted is simple enough to convert to JS:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">    
window.onload = function() {
    document.forms["SveForm2"].submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: i also think only JS is the last option . thanks a lot Shadow Wizard :)

Comment: @raj actually, this should be your first option and top priority. Client side VBScript is **bad**.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect IE 11 has changed the point at which the window.onload event is triggered, as I also have code which worked up to IE10, but behaves differently in IE11. If it IS the point at which the event is triggered, I don't think it will matter whether you are using VBScript or jscript to process the event.

I did see a post which indicated that IE was triggering the event too early, compared with other browsers, so maybe this is fixed in IE 11.